# How to implement database table of actions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I want to design table of actions, which simulates simple message action queue. Each row in the table is action to be done, which have its creation date, processing date and sending date and therefore status of execution. It might be possible that the action is restarted.

Also, some of the messages are not sent but attached to the other entities via mapping table. So the are different kind of messages, which can be indicated by the message_type integer field.

The Action table structure is now as follows (design draft) :

```
CREATE TABLE Action
(
id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
msg_id INT NOT NULL,
msg_type INT NOT NULL,
msg NVARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
creation_date DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
processing_date DATETIME2 NULL,
sending_date DATETIME2 NULL
status INT NOT NULL
)
```

The problem is that now each row contains "instance" of message sending action, the new row must be created if the action is restarted. This makes the sql query to the table little complex, because there must be limit for restarting actions for sending messages which are not sent. This possibly requires multiple self-joins to the table itself. The previous attempt must be saved, so this is the reason why previous row (a.k.a instance) of message action is not re-used.

I could try to retrieve the previous (re)starting attempt of the action by:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM Action a INNER JOIN Action b ON a.msg_id = b.msg_id
```

So if there are rows resulting from this inner join, there must be message actions in the table which has been restarted at least once. But this is not sufficient for solution because there might be several restarting attempts, therefore several INNER JOINs/self-joins.

How can the table can be redesigned so that It could be used efficiently for storing message actions, and previous attempts of restarting? Or should I just redesign the query somehow?

Sample data to clarify the problem:

Rows:

```
id = 1, msg_id = 1, msg_type = 1, msg = "Administrator mail: Everything is fine", creation_date = 31/12/2016, status = 10

id = 2, msg_id = 2, msg_type = 1, msg = "Administrator mail: Please ensure that service is running", creation_date = 1/1/2017, status = 6

id = 3, msg_id = 2, msg_type = 1, msg = "Administrator mail: Please ensure that service is running", creation_date = 1/1/2017, status = 6

id = 4, msg_id = 2, msg_type = 1, msg = "Administrator mail: Please ensure that service is running", creation_date = 1/1/2017, status = 1
```

Meaning of status codes:

```
status 6 = action failed
status 1 = action enqueued
status 3 = action started
status 10 = action completed succesfully
```

Comment: Hard to understand your question as written.   Sample data and desired results would probably help.

Comment: Good point. added some data, is it enough? The design is that msg_id is used to group multiple attempts ("actions") of sending message. If that fails (status=6), it is restarted until either status goes to 10 (completion with success) or maximum number of restart attempts is reached

Comment: It would seem that you need a 'action master' table with the first instance of the action, then a 'action detail' table containing a log of actual retries etc. This might seem redundant as the detail table would be mostly the same as the master table. But I think over time you'll probably find that the two tables start satisfying more specific functionality.

Comment: @iltelko the sample data is a good start, now what results are you trying to get based on the sample data?

Comment: If I have rows 1-3, the row with id 4 should be generated. But sql query to create with this table is hard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you need is a count for each message id, you simply use the following.  I added a "where" clause to exclude messages with a completed status and a "having" clause to illustrate how you can restrict your set based on the count for a given msg_id.

```
select
    msg_id,
    count(msg_id) as msg_count
from Action
where msg_id not in
(
    select 
        msg_id
    from Action
    where Status = 10
)
group by msg_id
having count(msg_id) > 5
```

If you need to insert rows, make the "id" column and IDENTITY field and try something like this:

```
Insert Into Action
(
    msg_id,
    msg_type,
    msg,
    creation_date,
    status
)
select
    msg_id,
    1,               -- you didn't explain this field, but all the values are "1", so...
    'Administrator mail: Please ensure that service is running',
    get_date(),
    1                -- from your list of statuses
from Action
where msg_id not in
(
    select 
        msg_id
    from Action
    where Status = 10
)
group by msg_id
having count(msg_id) < 5       -- use whatever count criteria you want here, of course
```

Comment: But the need is to get all the rows which satisfy this condition. I could use something like SELECT msg_id FROM Action GROUP BY msg_id HAVING COUNT(*) < (MAX_RESTART_COUNT), but this a subquery which results all the rows. Only one row from each group is needed (but from all groups, possibly many rows), how can it be retrieved efficiently? After retrieving these rows, I could just "restart" the action by copying the row..

Comment: Are you saying that you only need one message for a given msg_id, but you need one message for every msg_id that has been restarted fewer times than a set threshold?  As Tab Alleman said in his initial comment, sample data and desired output would be VERY helpful here.

Comment: basicly it is the same message, but the task must be restarted if that fails. so the row gets duplicated with the same message text etc, but with different id. the msg_id is the same. I wonder if this not efficient solution. I added the sample data as you pointed out, thanks for the tip! I hope it will clarify the question

Comment: @iltelko, we still need sample output based on the sample data you posted.

Comment: It is enough to have these rows msg_id = 1 & count = 1 and msg_id = 2 & count =2 (if there are first 3 rows in the database)

Comment: @iltelko, I've modified my answer based on your most recent comments.

Comment: brilliant! this is handy solution. I would add self join / left outer join (plus where "right side is null" condition) instead of "not in" structure for performance reasons. but very good solution, thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad that idea started you down a workable path.  Good luck to you.